# How to get all array objects of an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an target array inside of an array object:

```
[ 
  { 
    _id: 'main1',
    target: [
      { _id: '1', foo: [bar] },
      { _id: '2', foo: [bar] }
    ]
  },
  { 
    _id: 'main2',
    target: [
      { _id: '3', foo: [bar] },
      { _id: '4', foo: [bar] }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to get all target objects as one array:

**Needed result**

```
targets: [
  { _id: '1', foo: [bar] },
  { _id: '2', foo: [bar] }
  { _id: '3', foo: [bar] },
  { _id: '4', foo: [bar] }
]
```

I tried to use a `map()`

```
array.map(item => item.target)
```

But this results in a nested array like: `[ [ { _id: '1', foo: [bar] } ] ]`

```js
var array = [ 
      { 
        _id: 'main1',
        target: [
          { _id: '1', foo: ["bar"] },
          { _id: '2', foo: ["bar"] }
        ]
      },
      { 
        _id: 'main2',
        target: [
          { _id: '3', foo: ["bar"] },
          { _id: '4', foo: ["bar"] }
        ]
      }
    ]

console.log(
  array.map(item => item.target)
)
```

Comment: If you have a library like underscore or lodash, you could use the flatmap function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concat` to join arrays. Use spread operator and `map` to loop thru the array.

```js
let arr = [{_id:'main1',target:[{_id:'1',foo:['bar']},{_id:'2',foo:['bar']}]},{_id:'main2',target:[{_id:'3',foo:['bar']},{_id:'4',foo:['bar']}]}];
let result = [].concat(...arr.map(o => o.target));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [ 
  { 
    _id: 'main1',
    target: [
      { _id: '1', foo: ["bar"] },
      { _id: '2', foo: ["bar"] }
    ]
  },
  { 
    _id: 'main2',
    target: [
      { _id: '3', foo: ["bar"] },
      { _id: '4', foo: ["bar"] }
    ]
  }
]
var result =  arr.reduce((a,o) => a.concat(o.target), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this. This is a correct answer (see my similar one as well). You can use the ... operator instead of concat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It loops through an Array (similarly to `map()`) but creating a new result as it goes.

```
array.reduce((result, current) => {
    result = [...result, ...current.target]
    return result;
}, []);
```

Or, if you cannot use [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you can use `concat()` instead:

```
array.reduce((result, current) => {
    result = result.concat(current.target);
    return result;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
      {
        _id: 'main1',
        target: [
          { _id: '1', foo: ["bar"] },
          { _id: '2', foo: ["bar"] }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: 'main2',
        target: [
          { _id: '3', foo: ["bar"] },
          { _id: '4', foo: ["bar"] }
        ]
      }
    ] ;

  var result=[];
  for(var key in array){
    target=array[key].target;
    for(var kt in target){
      result.push(target[kt]);
    }
  }

  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method ( [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) )

This answer checks for the property `target` before concatenating.

```
let targets = obj_arr.reduce((a,c)=>c.target&&a.concat(c.target),[]);
```

```js
let obj_arr = [{
    _id: 'main1',
    target: [{
        _id: '1',
        foo: [""]
      },
      {
        _id: '2',
        foo: [""]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'main2',
    target: [{
        _id: '3',
        foo: [""]
      },
      {
        _id: '4',
        foo: [""]
      }
    ]
  }
]

let targets = obj_arr.reduce((accumulator, current_value) =>
      current_value.target&&accumulator.concat(current_value.target), []);


console.log(targets);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var foo = [
  {
    "_id": "main1",
    "target": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "foo": "[bar]"
      },
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "foo": "[bar]"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "main2",
    "target": [
      {
        "_id": "3",
        "foo": "[bar]"
      },
      {
        "_id": "4",
        "foo": "[bar]"
      }
    ]
  }
]
var bar = [];
foo.map(function(val) { 
 bar = bar.concat(val.target);
})
console.log(bar)
```